# Hyperbola instead of ellipse. Note the code below to the ellipse, there is a similar code for and hyperbole?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1];

\draw (0,0) ellipse (5 and 3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You do mean a _hyperbola_ not _hyperbole_, correct?

Comment: I am no tikz expert, but I don't think there is `hyperbola` graphics primitive in tikz. But it might be able with pgfplots

Answer (score 5):

This uses the `pgfplots` package and the ability to do parametric plots.

A hyperbola can be defined via parameter as

```
x = a*cosh(t)
y = b*sinh(t)
```

a and b meaning the 'major' and 'minor' axis parameters.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}




\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12,
  grid=none,
  axis lines=none,
  width=8cm,
  height=8cm,
  scale only axis,
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1];

%\draw (0,0) ellipse (5 and 3);
\begin{axis}
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-1:1,variable=\t]({2*cosh(t)},{1*sinh(t)});
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-1:1,variable=\t]({-2*cosh(t)},{1*sinh(t)}); % left hyperbolic branch

\addplot[samples=201,domain=0:360,variable=\t]({5*cos(t)},{3*sin(t)}); % Draw the ellipse

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]